# Point of contact of 2 OBBs?

Tags: java, math, geometry

I'm working on the physics for my GTA2-like game so I can learn more about game physics.

The collision detection and resolution are working great.

I'm now just unsure how to compute the point of contact when I hit a wall.

Here is my OBB class:

```
public class OBB2D
{
   private Vector2D projVec = new Vector2D();
   private static Vector2D projAVec = new Vector2D();
   private static Vector2D projBVec = new Vector2D();
   private static Vector2D tempNormal = new Vector2D();
   private Vector2D deltaVec = new Vector2D();


// Corners of the box, where 0 is the lower left.
   private  Vector2D corner[] = new Vector2D[4];

   private Vector2D center = new Vector2D();
   private Vector2D extents = new Vector2D();

   private RectF boundingRect = new RectF();
   private float angle;

    //Two edges of the box extended away from corner[0]. 
   private  Vector2D axis[] = new Vector2D[2];

   private double origin[] = new double[2];

   public OBB2D(float centerx, float centery, float w, float h, float angle)
    {
       for(int i = 0; i < corner.length; ++i)
       {
           corner[i] = new Vector2D();
       }
       for(int i = 0; i < axis.length; ++i)
       {
           axis[i] = new Vector2D();
       }
       set(centerx,centery,w,h,angle);
    }

   public OBB2D(float left, float top, float width, float height)
  {
       for(int i = 0; i < corner.length; ++i)
       {
           corner[i] = new Vector2D();
       }
       for(int i = 0; i < axis.length; ++i)
       {
           axis[i] = new Vector2D();
       }
       set(left + (width / 2), top + (height / 2),width,height,0.0f);
   }

   public void set(float centerx,float centery,float w, float h,float angle)
   {
       float vxx = (float)Math.cos(angle);
       float vxy = (float)Math.sin(angle);
       float vyx = (float)-Math.sin(angle);
       float vyy = (float)Math.cos(angle);

           vxx *= w / 2;
           vxy *= (w / 2);
           vyx *= (h / 2);
           vyy *= (h / 2);

           corner[0].x = centerx - vxx - vyx;
           corner[0].y = centery - vxy - vyy;
           corner[1].x = centerx + vxx - vyx;
           corner[1].y = centery + vxy - vyy;
           corner[2].x = centerx + vxx + vyx;
           corner[2].y = centery + vxy + vyy;
           corner[3].x = centerx - vxx + vyx;
           corner[3].y = centery - vxy + vyy;

           this.center.x = centerx;
           this.center.y = centery;
           this.angle = angle;
           computeAxes();
           extents.x = w / 2;
           extents.y = h / 2;

           computeBoundingRect();
   }


   //Updates the axes after the corners move.  Assumes the
   //corners actually form a rectangle.
   private void computeAxes()
   {
       axis[0].x = corner[1].x - corner[0].x;
       axis[0].y = corner[1].y - corner[0].y;
       axis[1].x = corner[3].x - corner[0].x;
       axis[1].y = corner[3].y - corner[0].y;


       // Make the length of each axis 1/edge length so we know any
       // dot product must be less than 1 to fall within the edge.

       for (int a = 0; a < axis.length; ++a) 
       {
        float l = axis[a].length();
        float ll = l * l;
        axis[a].x = axis[a].x / ll;
        axis[a].y = axis[a].y / ll;
           origin[a] = corner[0].dot(axis[a]);
       }
   }



   public void computeBoundingRect()
   {
       boundingRect.left = JMath.min(JMath.min(corner[0].x, corner[3].x), JMath.min(corner[1].x, corner[2].x));
       boundingRect.top = JMath.min(JMath.min(corner[0].y, corner[1].y),JMath.min(corner[2].y, corner[3].y));
       boundingRect.right = JMath.max(JMath.max(corner[1].x, corner[2].x), JMath.max(corner[0].x, corner[3].x));
       boundingRect.bottom = JMath.max(JMath.max(corner[2].y, corner[3].y),JMath.max(corner[0].y, corner[1].y)); 
   }

   public void set(RectF rect)
   {
       set(rect.centerX(),rect.centerY(),rect.width(),rect.height(),0.0f);
   }

    // Returns true if other overlaps one dimension of this.
    private boolean overlaps1Way(OBB2D other)
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < axis.length; ++a) {

            double t = other.corner[0].dot(axis[a]);

            // Find the extent of box 2 on axis a
            double tMin = t;
            double tMax = t;

            for (int c = 1; c < corner.length; ++c) {
                t = other.corner[c].dot(axis[a]);

                if (t < tMin) {
                    tMin = t;
                } else if (t > tMax) {
                    tMax = t;
                }
            }

            // We have to subtract off the origin

            // See if [tMin, tMax] intersects [0, 1]
            if ((tMin > 1 + origin[a]) || (tMax < origin[a])) {
                // There was no intersection along this dimension;
                // the boxes cannot possibly overlap.
                return false;
            }
        }

        // There was no dimension along which there is no intersection.
        // Therefore the boxes overlap.
        return true;
    }



    public void moveTo(float centerx, float centery) 
    {
        float cx,cy;

        cx = center.x;
        cy = center.y;

        deltaVec.x = centerx - cx;
        deltaVec.y  = centery - cy;


        for (int c = 0; c < 4; ++c)
        {
            corner[c].x += deltaVec.x;
            corner[c].y += deltaVec.y;
        }

        boundingRect.left += deltaVec.x;
        boundingRect.top += deltaVec.y;
        boundingRect.right += deltaVec.x;
        boundingRect.bottom += deltaVec.y;


        this.center.x = centerx;
        this.center.y = centery;
        computeAxes();
    }

    // Returns true if the intersection of the boxes is non-empty.
    public boolean overlaps(OBB2D other)
    {
        if(right() < other.left())
        {
            return false;
        }

        if(bottom() < other.top())
        {
            return false;
        }

        if(left() > other.right())
        {
            return false;
        }

        if(top() > other.bottom())
        {
            return false;
        }


        if(other.getAngle() == 0.0f && getAngle() == 0.0f)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return overlaps1Way(other) && other.overlaps1Way(this);
    }

    public Vector2D getCenter()
    {
        return center;
    }

    public float getWidth()
    {
        return extents.x * 2;
    }

    public float getHeight() 
    {
        return extents.y * 2;
    }

    public void setAngle(float angle)
    {
        set(center.x,center.y,getWidth(),getHeight(),angle);
    }

    public float getAngle()
    {
        return angle;
    }

    public void setSize(float w,float h)
    {
        set(center.x,center.y,w,h,angle);
    }

    public float left()
    {
        return boundingRect.left;
    }

    public float right()
    {
        return boundingRect.right;
    }

    public float bottom()
    {
        return boundingRect.bottom;
    }

    public float top()
    {
        return boundingRect.top;
    }

    public RectF getBoundingRect()
    {
        return boundingRect;
    }

    public boolean overlaps(float left, float top, float right, float bottom)
    {
        if(right() < left)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if(bottom() < top)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if(left() > right)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if(top() > bottom)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static float distance(float ax, float ay,float bx, float by)
    {
      if (ax < bx)
        return bx - ay;
      else
        return ax - by;
    }


    public Vector2D project(float ax, float ay)
    {
        projVec.x = Float.MAX_VALUE;
        projVec.y = Float.MIN_VALUE;

      for (int i = 0; i < corner.length; ++i)
      {
        float dot = Vector2D.dot(corner[i].x,corner[i].y,ax,ay);

        projVec.x = JMath.min(dot, projVec.x);
        projVec.y = JMath.max(dot, projVec.y);
      }

      return projVec;
    }

    public Vector2D getCorner(int c)
    {
        return corner[c];
    }

    public int getNumCorners()
    {
        return corner.length;
    }

    public static float collisionResponse(OBB2D a, OBB2D b,  Vector2D outNormal) 
    {

        float depth = Float.MAX_VALUE;


        for (int i = 0; i < a.getNumCorners() + b.getNumCorners(); ++i)
        {
            Vector2D edgeA;
            Vector2D edgeB;
            if(i >= a.getNumCorners())
            {
                edgeA = b.getCorner((i + b.getNumCorners() - 1) % b.getNumCorners());
                edgeB = b.getCorner(i % b.getNumCorners());
            }
            else
            {
                edgeA = a.getCorner((i + a.getNumCorners() - 1) % a.getNumCorners());
                edgeB = a.getCorner(i % a.getNumCorners());
            }

             tempNormal.x = edgeB.x -edgeA.x;
             tempNormal.y = edgeB.y - edgeA.y; 


          tempNormal.normalize();


          projAVec.equals(a.project(tempNormal.x,tempNormal.y));
          projBVec.equals(b.project(tempNormal.x,tempNormal.y));

          float distance = OBB2D.distance(projAVec.x, projAVec.y,projBVec.x,projBVec.y);

          if (distance > 0.0f)
          {
            return 0.0f;
          }
          else
          {
            float d = Math.abs(distance);

            if (d < depth)
            {
              depth = d;
              outNormal.equals(tempNormal);
            }
          }
        }

        float dx,dy;
        dx = b.getCenter().x - a.getCenter().x;
        dy = b.getCenter().y - a.getCenter().y;
        float dot = Vector2D.dot(dx,dy,outNormal.x,outNormal.y);
        if(dot > 0)
        {
            outNormal.x = -outNormal.x;
            outNormal.y = -outNormal.y;
        }

        return depth;
    }

    public Vector2D getMoveDeltaVec()
    {
    return deltaVec;
}
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm now just unsure how to compute the point of contact when I hit a
>   wall.

You can represent a wall with a simple plane.

**The OBB-vs-plane intersection** test is the simplest [`separating axis test`](http://www.codezealot.org/archives/55) of them all:

> If two convex objects don't intersect, then there is a plane where
>   the projection of these two objects will not intersect.

A box intersects plane only if the plane normal forms a separating axis. Compute the projection of the box center and the projected radius (4 dot products and a few adds) and you're good to go (you also get penetration depth `for free`).

**The condition looks as follows:**

|d| <= a1|n*A1| + a2|n*A2| + a3|n*A3|

Here:

`d` distance from the center of the box to the plane.

`a1...a3` the extents of the box from the center.

`n` normal of the plane

`A1...A3` the x,y,z-axis of the box

**Some pseudocode:**

```
//Test if OBB b intersects plane p
int TestOBBPlane(OBB b, Plane p)
{
   // Compute the projection interval radius of b onto L(t) = b.c + t * p.n
   float r = b.e[0]*Abs(Dot(p.n, b.u[0])) +
      b.e[1]*Abs(Dot(p.n, b.u[1])) +
      b.e[2]*Abs(Dot(p.n, b.u[2]));

   // Compute distance of box center from plane
   float s = Dot(p.n, b.c) – p.d;

   // Intersection occurs when distance s falls within [-r,+r] interval
   return Abs(s) <= r;
}
```

**The OBB-vs-OBB intersection** test is more complicated.

Let us refer to [this great tutorial](http://www.jkh.me/files/tutorials/Separating%20Axis%20Theorem%20for%20Oriented%20Bounding%20Boxes.pdf):

> In this case we no longer have corresponding separating lines that are
>   perpendicular to the separating axes. Instead, we have separating
>   planes that separate the bounding volumes (and they are perpendicular
>   to their corresponding separating axes).
>
> In 3D space, each OBB only has 3 unique planes extended by its faces,
>   and the separating planes are parallel to these faces. We are
>   interested in the separating planes parallel to the faces, but in 3D
>   space, the faces are not the only concern. We are also interested in
>   the edges. The separating planes of interest are parallel to the faces
>   of the boxes, and the separating axes of interest are perpendicular to
>   the separating planes. Hence the separating axes of interest are
>   perpendicular to the 3 unique faces of each box. Notice these 6
>   separating axes of interest correspond to the 6 local (XYZ) axes of
>   the two boxes.
>
> So there are 9 separating axes to consider for edges collision in
>   addition to the 6 separating axes we already have found for the faces
>   collision. This makes the total number of possible separating axes to
>   consider at 15.

Here are the 15 possible separating axes (L) you will need to test:

```
CASE 1:  L = Ax
CASE 2:  L = Ay
CASE 3:  L = Az
CASE 4:  L = Bx
CASE 5:  L = By
CASE 6:  L = Bz
CASE 7:  L = Ax x Bx
CASE 8:  L = Ax x By
CASE 9:  L = Ax x Bz
CASE 10: L = Ay x Bx
CASE 11: L = Ay x By
CASE 12: L = Ay x Bz
CASE 13: L = Az x Bx
CASE 14: L = Az x By
CASE 15: L = Az x Bz
```

Here:

`Ax` unit vector representing the x-axis of A

`Ay` unit vector representing the y-axis of A

`Az` unit vector representing the z-axis of A

`Bx` unit vector representing the x-axis of B

`By` unit vector representing the y-axis of B

`Bz` unit vector representing the z-axis of B

Now you can see the algorithm behind the OBB-OBB intersection test.

**Let's jump to the source code:**

2D OBB-OBB: http://www.flipcode.com/archives/2D_OBB_Intersection.shtml

3D OBB-OBB: http://www.geometrictools.com/LibMathematics/Intersection/Intersection.html

**P.S:** This link http://www.realtimerendering.com/intersections.html will be useful to those, who wish to go beyond planes and boxes.

Comment: Could you also add OBB vs OBB, cars also need to collide. Thanks, great answer :)

Comment: Ok, i will, just need some time, because it is much more complicated.

Comment: Mine is in 2D so I take it the Z axis can be eliminated.

Comment: By ``test`` i mean to test some axis as the separating axis.

Comment: Could you place an example of 1 of these tests using the source code you linked?

Comment: And show how the point of intersection can be returned from its success.

Comment: Under the section ``Some pseudocode:`` there is a code to test exactly one separating axis (plane normal).

Comment: So a plane has a normal and an axis?

Comment: Plane normal is the axis in this case. We test if it is indeed a separating axis.

Comment: Plane equation has 4 parameters: ``ax + by + cz + d = 0``. ``d`` is the distance from origin to the plane.

Comment: There are 2 axes, which axe do I use?

Comment: Vector (a,b,c) is what you need. Exactly this is done in ``Some pseudocode:`` example.

Comment: I'm just not sure how to come up with the Plane object, I don't have a Plane class. Sorry, I'm really trying to understand this. Thanks

Comment: class Plane { float a,b,c,d; }

Comment: Yes, but, I need to perform  the test for each separating axis, in my class, say for the first axis, how would I come up with a b c d?
Thanks

Comment: The 1st case is ``Ax``, so it is the x-axis of your box.

Comment: An axis is just a vector though, you'd be missing C D in A B C D

Comment: Vector + distance from origin. For a 2D case it will be: A B D

Comment: Okay it's all making sense now. Thanks a bunch for all the help, you've earned your 500 points :)

Comment: But I can only give them to you in 5 hours :(

Comment: Hmmm one more thing, how exactly do I get the point of intersection from this?

Comment: If box intersects plane you can check ray intersection with every vertex of the box: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/429443-obb-ray-and-obb-plane-intersection/

Comment: Hmm all those functions seem to return a bool if they intersect but they don't seem to return the point of intersection...

Comment: It is designed to do a fast ``test``. If you need intersection point you need to check ray intersection if the test is positive.

Comment: Since the goal of the question is to find the Point of intersection, could you please add a section on this to your answer and briefly describe how the ray intersection is used in conjunction with test to find the point of intersection? Thanks

Comment: There is no point of intersection. Box-Plane intersection will result in a convex polygon. You can project 8 vertices of the box on the plane and construct a convex hull of these 8 projections. This will be the intersection result. In case you just need to generate a collision response, you can check the distances of vertices to a plane to find penetration distance. It is unclear what exactly you want, but there is definitely no "point" of intersection even in 2D case.